# How to link a particular function in SLOT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

This is my Wavefrontrenderer class.

```
Class WavefrontRenderer : public QMainWindow , private 
 Ui::WavefrontRendererClass
{
Q_OBJECT
//Q_PROPERTY( QColor m_color READ m_color NOTIFY colorChanged)

 public:

 WavefrontRenderer(TreeModel* model , QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
 void iterate(const QModelIndex & index, const QAbstractItemModel * model);
 void render();
 void RenderTreeElement(QModelIndex index); 

 private:
//Ui::WavefrontRendererClass ui;
TextureManager textureManager;
TextureManagerCubeMap textureManagerCubeMap;
QColor  m_color;
void FillComboBox();

 private slots:
  void PositionXYZ();

};
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 WavefrontRenderer::WavefrontRenderer(TreeModel* model , QWidget *parent) : 
 QMainWindow(parent)
 {
  setupUi(this);
  treeView->setModel(model);
  treeView->setDragEnabled(true);
  treeView->setAcceptDrops(true);
  treeView->installEventFilter(this);
  connect(doubleSpinBoxPositionX, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this , 
  SLOT(PositionXYZ()));

   }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am creating controls at runtime from another class to which i pass the Wavefrontrenderer class as a pointer.

```
void Container::CreateUI(QHBoxLayout* layout)
 {
    wavefrontrenderer // Pointer defined as a private member    
    QDoubleSpinBox *PositionXSpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
    PositionXSpinBox->setRange(-10000, 10000);
    PositionXSpinBox->setSingleStep(.1);
    PositionXSpinBox->setValue(x);
    layout->addWidget(PositionXSpinBox);
    bool ok = QObject::connect(PositionXSpinBox, 
    SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), wavefrontrenderer , SLOT(print()));
    qDebug() << "The  slot is connected =" << ok;
```

}

I have defined print as a public slot member in Container class.

The issue is that the connect tries to locate print() function in WavefrontRenderer class rather than Container class.

How can i make connect call the print() funtion of the Container class.

Comment: Replace `bool ok = QObject::connect(PositionXSpinBox, 
    SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), wavefrontrenderer , SLOT(print()));` by `bool ok = QObject::connect(PositionXSpinBox, 
    SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this , SLOT(print()));`. If you are using Qt 5, you should consider to use the new connection syntax.

Comment: @Romha Korev i get this error when i replace with this ,  none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: do i need to type cast my container class.

Comment: Container has to inherit from QObject

Comment: Thanks for the help it is working now.